# How to pass multiple build parameter value for a Jenkins job using Rest Assured?

Tags: jenkins, rest-assured, jenkins-api

I want to remotely build a jenkins job using multiple parameter through restassured API jobs in java.
I tried using the following link

```
http://localhost:8080/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&FEATURE="parameter1_value";FEATURE2=parameter2_value
```

but this url results in triggering a job with passing both the parameter values within a single parameter.

```
get("http://localhost:8080/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&FEATURE="parameter1_value";FEATURE2=parameter2_value");
```

[image: This is how the above link results in]

This is the response json of jenkins job

[image: This is the response json on jenkins job]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter defined in configuration of a Jenkins job should be a "String Parameter" in order to set them using URL.
And the modified URL should be like -

```
http://localhost:8080/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?parameter=parameter1_value&parameter2=parameter2_value
```

Comment: The '&" results in a heading and tailing space